# How do I use PHP and MySQL to have a table x columns wide?

Tags: php, mysql, rows, tabular

I have a MySQL table, in which are a number of values.  I want these values to be put into a table.  The resulting page will be fed through a HTML to PDF script and it seems not to like floats for some reason, so I figured a table would be the best fail-safe method.  The table should be 7 columns wide, but my data exceeds that and will continue to grow.  How do I tell my PHP script that, after every seven items (7, 14, 21, etc.), we start a new row?

Also, how would the script alter if two variables are in the same cell? Say an icon URL (call it $iconURL) and a piece of descriptive text (call it $desTXT)? I am a PHP noob and don't really know how it would work, I'm just getting to grips with calling the information from a database as it is.

Comment: how exactly is your data structured, and with what query are you retrieving it?

Answer (score 1):

Set a counter in your loop as you're going through the rows.

If the counter reaches 7 (or 6 if you do it from 0), insert a conditional statement for the break. Then reset the counter.